# Counting Upper Case words in a variable in python

Tags: python, text, uppercase

I have a variable with some sort of review text. I want to create a new variable which has  the count of uppercase words in the text.

**For Example:**

Review_1: "This was a great product"

Answer_1:Uppercase_word:0

Review_2: "This was NOT AT ALL GOOD"

Answer_2: uppercase_word:4

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] :)

Comment: `word == word.upper()` will tell you if a word contains all uppercase letters.

Comment: Sure Thanks. I will take that tour. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`str.isupper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) returns a boolean (`True` or `False`) if a string is entirely uppercased.

In Python `1 == True` and `0 == False` so you can [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) booleans.

The only thing left is to split the original string into words using [`.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

```
sum(map(str.isupper, "This was a great product".split()))  # 0
sum(map(str.isupper, "This was NOT AT ALL GOOD".split()))  # 4
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives error saying : isupper() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: @prasadvaidya If you literally just copy and paste into a Python3 shell, this works.

Comment: Yeah it works Thanks , I guess I already had 'str' assigned as something else and so it was giving error. How can I use this over a variable which has  text reviews?

Comment: @prasadvaidya Just place the variable where the string is. You probably want to ask a new question if that doesn't make sense.