# Creating a mapper that find the capitalized words in a text

Tags: python, mapper

Implement filescounter, which takes a string in any variety and returns the number of capitalized words in that string, inclusive of the last and first character.

```py
def filescounter(s):
    sr=0
    for words in text:
        #...
    return sr
```

I'm stuck on how to go about this.

Comment: Use Regular Expression https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#:~:text=Regular%20expressions%20%28called%20REs%2C%20or%20regexes%2C%20or%20regex,addresses%2C%20or%20TeX%20commands%2C%20or%20anything%20you%20like.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting Upper Case words in a variable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078267/counting-upper-case-words-in-a-variable-in-python)

Comment: Please read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Stack overflow is not a place to dump your homework questions.

Answer (score 1):

Split the text on whitespace then iterate through the words:

```py
def countCapitalized(text):
    count = 0
    for word in text.split():
        if word.isupper():
            count += 1
    return count
```

If, by capitalized, you mean only the first letter needs to be capitalized, then you can replace `word.isupper()` with `word[0].isupper()`.

Comment: First of all, "does this work" isn't a good question. Just test it yourself and see if it does. Second of all, `split` splits on all whitespace by default, including newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
def count_upper_words(text):
    return sum(1 for word in text.split() if word.isupper())
```

Explanation:

- split() chops text to words by either spaces or newlines
- so called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) works faster than an explicit for-loop and looks nicer

Comment: If I understood you correctly, it's already implemented and called `sum`. Does it work in your setting?